# Debugging Xamarin.Forms App on Android Oreo Fails

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, usb-debugging

Every time I run to debug app on my Nexus 6P (Android Oreo), the app will get deployed, starts briefly and then exits and Visual Studio (2015) will stop debug process and show following message

```
Android application is debugging.
Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
```

Checking Logcat shows lots of errors, 2 of which are predominant

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
09-29 13:03:50.240  Huawei Nexus 6P Error   11451   o.mz    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: o.ʖ
    at o.ʷ.ˏ(:363)
    at o.Г.ॱ(:247)
    at o.Г.ˋ(:141)
    at o.ץ.ˎ(:406)
    at o.ץ.ˋ(:4352)
    at o.ץ.ॱ(:244)
    at o.ץ.ˊ(:142)
    at o.ᴄ.ॱ(:476)
    at o.Ḯ.ˋ(:3890)
    at o.Ḯ.ॱ(:3784)
    at o.mz$If.onMessage(:3899)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$1.onMessage(:62)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.readMessageFrame(:242)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.WebSocketReader.processNextFrame(:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.readMessage(:97)
    at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(:152)
    at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(:41)
    at okhttp3.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(:97)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

and the 2nd and most dominant error is

```
 Time   Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
09-29 13:04:34.666  Huawei Nexus 6P Error   3759    QC-QMI  linux_qmi_qmux_io_wake_lock: Err in writing wakelock=qmuxd_port_wl_0, error [1:Operation not permitted]
```

Comment: Having a similar problem running from Android Studio. (Also on Nexus 6P running Android 8.0) Have you discovered any solutions?

Comment: Nope, but also on 8.0